# Landing gear sequence

Tags: landing-gear

{With reference to this video}

Is there any particular reason that land gear retract half way then 2nd gear retract half way and then proceed to retract completely.

Is it related to center of gravity (cog)?

2nd thing I noticed , Tyre boogie is tilted , is there any reason for it ?whats the mechanism behind it? I believed that aircraft land at particular angle , so that all wheel may contact ground at once .is it correct?

Comment: And [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/14569/62) probably answers your second point.

Comment: This cover all's thanks